Tv not detecting hdmi cable from computer
My TV (Samsung UN46EH5300FXZA) is not detecting my computer (Dell Inspiron-22-3263) although they are both connected together via HDMI. The computer is not detecting the TV either as far as I know. Secure Boot is disabled. The computer is using an Intel Core i3 with integrated graphics. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I'm not overly tech savvy.
